# Accidentally saw someone veilless

Tags: wudu, taharah

I accidentally saw a woman veilless while going to mosque. Do I have to perform a wudu again?

Comment: Do you mean you saw her face?

Answer (score 3):

Seeing something does not invalidate wudu, unless it is accompanied with discharge.

Reference: https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/162737/does-seeing-others-awrah-invalidate-ones-ablution